# sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start generates a "Unknown command: 'celeryd_multi'"

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm setting up celery to run daemonized, using the variables from my virtual environment. But when I run `$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start`, I get `Unknown command: 'celeryd_multi' Type 'manage.py help' for usage.`

I have set the following:

> CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/myuser/projects/myproject"
>   ENV_PYTHON="/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python"
>   CELERYD_MULTI="$ENV_PYTHON $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

When I run `$ /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python /home/myuser/projects/myproject/manage.py celeryd_multi` from the command line, it works fine.

Any ideas? I will gladly post any other code you need :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that when you run it as your user, virtualenv already has proper environment activated for your user "myuser" and it pulls packages from /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproject/...

When you do sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start you are starting celery as root which probably doesn't have virtualenv activated in /root/.virtualenvs/ if such a thing even exists and thus it looks for python packages in /usr/lib/... where your default python is and consequently where your celery is not installed.

Your options are to either:

1. Replicate the same virtualenv under root user and start it like you tried with sudo
2. Keep virtualenv where it is and start celery as your user "myuser" (no sudo) without using init scripts.
3. Write a script that will `su - myuser -c /bin/sh /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/celeryd` to invoke it from init.d as a myuser.
4. Install supervisor outside of virtualenv and let it do the dirtywork for you

Thoughts:

1. Avoid using root for anything you don't have to.
2. If you don't need celery to start on boot then this is fine, wrapped in a script possibly.
3. Plain hackish to me, but works if you don't want to invest additional 30min to use something else.
4. Probably best way to handle ALL of your python startup needs, highly recommended.

Comment: Thank you! I went with creating a bash script checking if celery is running, executed from cron. Not the best solution, but it was the easiest at the time.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you just set a wrong DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:

try: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings" <-> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings"

Comment: This suggestion worked for me -- I was using a celeryd script that I had created originally for a django project created in version 1.3.  The script didn't work any more because the settings file has moved for projects created with django 1.4.

Comment: This also helped me in my case.